# Wifi devices gone from the additional drivers list and Wifi stopped working

Tags: 16.04, drivers, wireless, additional-drivers

I got new laptop and activated additional drivers for some of devices (video, cpu firmware).

But after activation of custom drivers for the wifi adapter, I get an error. And now, no wifi devices appear the in connections manager (no internet) and the wifi card is not listed on the additional drivers settings page.

After, I get the same problem for Bluetooth. It was gone from the additional drivers settings page, but the Bluetooth device is still working.

How I can purge additional drivers settings?

My hardware:

- Ubuntu 16.04
- Dell laptop

Update:

```
$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A3
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:24fd] (rev 78)
  Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:0050]
```

I have deactivated Secure Boot, nothing changed

**UPDATE:**
Problem NOT in drivers. It works before. Dell laptop came with all drivers
The problem in Additional Drivers manager. After some manipulations it fails with error. Now, I tried to change driver for device with name **oem-bluez-autoenable**. After error, this device was gone from list, like it was before  for wifi

```
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/gtk/SoftwarePropertiesGtk.py:40: PyGIWarning: Gtk was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.
  from gi.repository import GObject, Gdk, Gtk, Gio, GLib
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/cache.py", line 194, in __getitem__
    return self._weakref[key]
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/weakref.py", line 131, in __getitem__
    o = self.data[key]()
KeyError: 'oem-bluez-autoenable'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/cache.py", line 198, in __getitem__
    rawpkg = self._cache[key]
KeyError: 'oem-bluez-autoenable'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/gtk/SoftwarePropertiesGtk.py", line 1047, in on_driver_changes_finish
    self.set_driver_action_status()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/gtk/SoftwarePropertiesGtk.py", line 1417, in set_driver_action_status
    pkg = self.apt_cache[pkg_name]
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/cache.py", line 200, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError('The cache has no package named %r' % key)
KeyError: "The cache has no package named 'oem-bluez-autoenable'"
```

[image: additional drivers manager before changin driver]
 [image: Error after change triver attempt]

Is it possible to fix it?

Comment: Could you post the full error message you got?

Comment: Disable Secure Boot.

Comment: @Pilot6 hm, It was updated (UEFI) during last system update, before problems with wifi. And it can be a reason. But I can't deactivate it. After deactivation, it can't find device for loading. Should I reinstall the system?

Comment: Secure Boot is disabled in the computer BIOS. You don't disable UEFI boot, but disable only Secure Boot.

Comment: @Pilot6, with disabled Secure Boot nothing changed

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` terminal command.

Comment: I think you have two (mostly) unrelated problems here: 1) the wireless adapter driver issue and 2) the broken *Additional Drivers* application. "purge additional drivers settings" requires removing a bogus or adding a correct driver (issue 1). "fix [Additional Drivers]" is issue 2. Unfortunately Ask Ubuntu's (and Stack Exchange's) Q&A model is ill suited to deal with multiple unrelated issues that broaden the scope of a question. Therefore could you please [edit] your question to narrow it down to either issue 1 or 2 and [open a new question](/questions/ask) for the other one? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To purge the 'Additional Drivers' for wireless, please open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
```

Reboot.

Comment: bcmwl-kernel-source not installed  and can't be deleted

Comment: Let's take a look at your exact wireless device; from the terminal: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3`

Comment: 02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:24fd] (rev 78)
 Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:0050]

Comment: Driver works before, and stopped working, I think, this question is not a duplicate

Comment: Please let us see: `modinfo iwlwifi | grep 24FD` and also: `rfkill list all`